# «За вопрос можно будет назначить премию N минут назад»

Tags: дефект, локализация, конкурс

Оставил [**страницу**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618298/199934) открытой в браузере и отошёл от компьютера. Когда вернулся, увидел сообщение:

> за вопрос можно будет назначить премию 20 мин. назад

[image: Премия]

Это не по-русски. Логичнее всего, видимо, когда время подошло, сменить сообщение на «начать конкурс».

[image: Правильно]

Comment: Думаю, дело не в локализации, а счётчике-таймере на сайте.

Comment: @Other возможно даже не на сайте, а в браузере. Это дело скорее всего обновляется без запроса с сервера.

Comment: @alexolut, я так и сказал. Лень в сорцы лезть и глядеть как там `setTimeout` работает.

Comment: @Other ну, сказали Вы всё же иначе :) А вот что имели в виду, дело другое.

Comment: @alexolut, не знаю, для меня эта фраза вполне про таймеры в JS. Но не суть важно. Главное что это не проблема локализации.

Comment: @Other да. Это хорошо, что не локализация :) Но если бы была локализация, можно было бы поправить самостоятельно.

Comment: @alexolut, NicolasChabanovsky вроде говорил что issue оперативно прикрывают.

Comment: У меня была мысль, что причина не в локализации, но оставил метку `локализация`, поскольку можно и исправить проблему на что-то вроде `можно назначить премию уже как 20 минут`. Спасибо.

Comment: Локализацией проблему не решить т.к. там одна строка вида `question eligible for bounty $when$` для которой `$when` переводится отдельно в нечто подобное `20 мин. назад`.

Comment: @Other что Вы подразумеваете под issue в данном случае? Проблемы ранжируются, и если они не особо важны они могут быть вообще никогда не исправлены. А данная проблема как раз такого рода, имхо, т.е. возникает в момент перехода через дату начала конкурса, если не обновить страницы в ручном режиме. Если я правильно понял суть.

Comment: После ручного обновления страницы, текст показывается правильно?

Comment: @alexolut, даа.

Comment: @alexolut, имел ввиду тикет в системе типа JIRA. Да, сложноуловимая проблема. Наподобие той, что бывает если отправить коммент, а он долго не отправляется. Выводится ошибка непереведённая.

Comment: @Other делайте скриншоты :) По упомянутой Вами ошибке только что утвердил строки. Вижу, Вы перевод делали 2 месяца назад.

Comment: @alexolut, целых 2 месяца??? Эта проблема никогда не решиться :) Тут явно формируется строка по счётчику, который банально забыли лишить знака.